# Absolute Value of Horizontal Spacing in Numcases

Tags: spacing, cases

I am interested in the absolute value of the horizontal spacing which is automatically assigned by `numcases` before an alignment point. For instance, what is the spacing after the comma and before "(case 2)" in the following example? The reason I am asking is that I would like to make this spacing uniform in different equations. When using e.g. `alignat`, I apparently have to manually enter a space before the second alignment point. Alternatively, is there a way to manually set this spacing when using `numcases`?

This is the example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{|x|=}
x, & (case 1)\\
-x, & (case 2)
\end{numcases}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& 1+2=3 & \quad & \text{(equation 1)}, \\
& 2+2=4 & \quad & \text{(equation 2)}, \\
& 3+2=5 & \quad & \text{(equation 3)}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the original question and hope that clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `cases` it's better to use the more powerful package `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={|x|=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
x, & \quad & \text{(case 1)}\\
-x, & \quad & \text{(case 2)}
\end{empheq}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& 1+2=3 & \quad & \text{(equation 1)}, \\
& 2+2=4 & \quad & \text{(equation 2)}, \\
& 3+2=5 & \quad & \text{(equation 3)}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]